# Why can't i access newly loaded DOM elements in the .load() callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and jQuery, so i think i have some sort of misunderstanding of how this stuff is supposed to work. What i do is load some html via .load(), then i call a previously defined function as the callback function. This function is not doing the same as when i define it directly in place:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#playerslot').html( '' ).load('player/',function(){
        $('#new_element').replaceWith('Hello World!')
    });
});
```

The code above works, while this one does not:

```
function hello(){
    $('#new_element').replaceWith('Hello World!')
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playerslot').html( '' ).load('player/',hello());
});
```

Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the callback as `hello()`, the function is actually being called right then, and the result is what is assigned to be the callback.  Instead, you should either do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playerslot').html( '' ).load('player/', hello);
});
```

or (and this is necessary if you need to pass parameters to the function called within the callback) you can wrap your function in an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playerslot').html( '' ).load('player/', function() {hello()});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (notice no parentheses after `hello`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playerslot').html( '' ).load('player/', hello);
});
```

Whenever you pass a function to another function to be called later (this is known as a *callback*), you omit the parentheses because you don't want the function to be called now, you want the other function to call it later.  Think of it as a way of giving the *name* of the function to be called later.

Answer (score 1):

`hello()` calls the function immediately and supplies it return value (`undefined`) as the parameter of `load`. You need to provide a reference to `hello` to `load` instead:

```
 $('#playerslot').html( '' ).load('player/',hello);
```